# Reading and writing binary information with C++

Tags: c++, file-io, binaryfiles

I'm having some trouble reading and writing binary information. I can successfully write a simple string to a text file, in this case, my file 'output.dat' contains the sentence "Hello, this is a sentence".

However, I cannot read my information back. I cannot identify the problem. I intend to change every byte of the information read from the binary file later on so returning the value as a string helps.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void write(const string &input) {
    fstream output("output.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);
    if (output.is_open()) {
        output.write(input.c_str(), input.size());
        output.close();
    }
}

string read(const string &fname) {
    int size;
    char* buffer;
    fstream input(fname, ios::in | ios::binary);
    if (input.is_open()) {
        input.seekg(0, ios::end);
        size = input.tellg();
        input.seekg(0, ios::beg);
        buffer = new char[size];
        input.read(buffer, size);
        input.close();
    }
    string result(buffer);
    return result;
}

int main () {
    cout << read("output.dat") << endl;

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code above? It just worked fine with me. You are not writing anything to the file to expect anything.

Comment: I think the whole problem was when I rewrote my read function. I forgot to initialize the size of the buffer. My only problem now is how do I add 5 to every byte before writing the information?

Comment: Your updated code is leaking memory. [**Do not use pointers and `new` here**](http://klmr.me/slides/modern-cpp/)

Comment: It's not a big deal considering it's for a class exercise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bug is here.

```
char* buffer;
input.read(buffer, size);
```

You're reading to the memory that `buffer` is pointing to.

But where is it pointing to?  The pointer `buffer` has never been initialized.

If you know how much space you need, an approach like this will work.

```
std::vector<char> buffer(size);
input.read(&buffer.front(), size);
```

Comment: "If you know how much space you need", the space needed is `size`. I think `char buffer[size];` might work in some compilers?

Comment: What if I'm not sure how much space I'll need. Thanks by the way.

Comment: A fixed buffer is virtually never the correct answer. Just use a `std::vector`.

Comment: Oh my mistake, I merely forgot to write this in. I used size to specify the size of buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I really cannot understand what is going wrong in this code, as it looks fine, and works fine with me. Nevertheless, the buffer you are allocating is missing the null terminator to mark char-string end. Just change it to this:

```
buffer = new char[size+1];
input.read(buffer, size);
buffer[size] = 0;
```

Comment: Yes, I merely forgot to add one line and specify the size of the buffer. I feel like an idiot, but at least it works now.